# How to make the output react to the function?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a total value output. And I need it to get decreased when a checkbox is unchecked. It works, but not with the function I have for unchecking the box.

**Jquery Total value output:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var begin = 720;
  $("#yett").val('Total €' + begin.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ','));
  $("#CalculatorPlacing").on("change", function() {
    var prev = $("#yett").val().split('€')[1];
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
      total = begin - 300;
      $("#yett").val('Total €' + total.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ','));
    }else{
      $("#yett").val('Total €' + begin.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ','));
    }
  });
});
```

**Jquery Unchecking the box:**

```
$('#CalculatorTransport').change(function() {
  if ($('#CalculatorTransport').is(':checked') == true) { // off
    $("#CalculatorPlacing").attr("disabled", true);
    $('#CalculatorPlacing').prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

**Value output:**

```
<div class="SummaryRow">
  <h1><input type="yeets" name="_mdjm_event_cost" id="yett" class="mdjm-input-currency required" readonly="readonly" value="" placeholder="Totaal €0.00" style="
        height: 100px;
        width: 275px;
        margin-top: -40px;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;" />
  </h1>
</div>
```

**Both checkboxes:**

```
<div class="switch" onclick="TotaalOfferte()">
   <input type="checkbox" name="iCalculatorTransport" id="CalculatorTransport" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round AutosubmitCalculator" value="0" tabindex="4">
   <label for="CalculatorTransport" data-on="JA" data-off="NEE"></label>
</div>


<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iCalculatorPlacing" id="CalculatorPlacing" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round AutosubmitCalculator" value="1" tabindex="5">
  <label for="CalculatorPlacing" data-on="JA" data-off="NEE"></label>
</div>
```

When I uncheck the checkbox "CalculatorTransport" it also unchecks the "CalculatorPlacing" checkbox, but my total value function doesnt react to it. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MDN doc on `change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change):

> Unlike the `input` event, the `change` event is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value.

Instead, the recommendation is to user MutationObserver. So your code could be rewritten as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var begin = 720;
  $("#yett").val("Total €" + begin.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ","));

  var target = document.querySelector("#CalculatorPlacing");
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    checked = mutations[0].target.checked;
    var prev = $("#yett")
      .val()
      .split("€")[1];
    if (checked === true) {
      total = begin - 300;
      $("#yett").val("Total €" + total.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ","));
    } else {
      $("#yett").val("Total €" + begin.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ","));
    }
  });
  var config = { attributes: true };
  observer.observe(target, config);

  $("#CalculatorPlacing").on("change", function() {
    var prev = $("#yett")
      .val()
      .split("€")[1];
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      total = begin - 300;
      $("#yett").val("Total €" + total.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ","));
    } else {
      $("#yett").val("Total €" + begin.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ","));
    }
  });

  $("#CalculatorTransport").change(function() {
    if ($("#CalculatorTransport").is(":checked") == true) {
      // off
      $("#CalculatorPlacing").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#CalculatorPlacing").prop("checked", true);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the question correct you can do something similar to this. See the comments in the snippet for more details

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = $('#yett').text();  
  $(".switch").on('change', function(event){
  
      // remove $  
      total = total.substring(0, total.length-1);   
      
      //check if clicked checkbox is checked
      if($(this).is(":checked")){       
       //subtract clicked input by the "subtractby" value (from the HTML)
        total = ~~total - ~~($(this).attr('subtractby'));   
      }
      else{      
      //add to the clicked input by the "subtractby" value (from the HTML)         
        total = ~~total + ~~($(this).attr('subtractby'));   
      }                 
      
      //add back the $
      total = total + "$"; 
      
      //update the text
      $('#yett').text(total);      
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="SummaryRow">
  <h1 id="yett">1000$</h1>
</div>


<div>
  <label>-187</label>
  <input class="switch" type="checkbox" subtractby="187">
</div>

<div>
  <label>-27</label>
  <input class="switch" type="checkbox" subtractby="27">
</div>
```

Comment: `is(':checked')` is boolean in itself. No need to complicate with `== true`. That's my approach too.

Comment: @yardpenalty I dont follow.. what exactly do you mean?

Comment: i upvoted your answer. You used the if statement correctly. He wrote it where it could cause erroneous results. When using `is(:checked)` no need to use `== true` or `=== true` because it's already explicit.

Comment: @yardpenalty ahh I see